# Resources and layout direction rendered incorrectly only on Android 8.0 and above

Tags: android, android-layout, locale, android-8.0-oreo

I have a multilingual app with primary language English and secondary language Arabic.

I am calling `setLocale()` in the `onCreate()` of every `Activity` in my app:

```
public static void setLocale(Locale locale){
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Context context = MyApplication.getInstance();
    final Resources resources = context.getResources();
    final Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

where `locale` is one of the following:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The above method is called *before* `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` gets called.

As described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL),

- I have added `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the manifest.
- I have changed all xml properties with `left` and `right` attributes to `start` and `end` respectively.
- I have put Arabic-language strings in `res\values-ar\strings` folder and drawable resources in `res\drawable-ar` folder (and similarly for other resources).

The above setup works properly. After changing the `Locale` to `ar-AE`, Arabic text & resources are correctly displayed in my Activities.

However, there is a problem with both resources and layout direction for all Android devices with version **8.0** and above.

On a device with version less than 8.0, an RTL screen ***correctly*** looks like this:

[image]

And on all devices with 8.0+, the same screen turns up looking like this:

[image]

which is ***wrong***.

> It turns out that both the direction and the resources are getting
>   displayed incorrectly.

There are *two* problems here:

- The correct `Locale` does not seem to be updated across the app configuration.
- The direction of the text and drawables is opposite of what it should be.

With respect to direction, a curious method called [`setLayoutDirection()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#setLayoutDirection(java.util.Locale)) exists which I had not noticed before.

I would like to know what this problem is, why it happens in Oreo and what is the solution for it. Please help / comment on this.

**EDIT**:

> According to the [API Differences
>   report](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/25/changes), the
>   [`updateConfiguration()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#updateConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics))
>   method was indeed deprecated in Android 7.1 (API level 25).

Also, found all the relevant posts on this. In order of importance:

**1.** [Android N change language programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39705739).

**2.** [Android context.getResources.updateConfiguration() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40221711).

**3.** [How to change Android O / Oreo / api 26 app language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47165311).

**4.** [Android RTL issue in API 24 and higher on locale change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44515264)

**5.** [Change language programmatically (Android N 7.0 - API 24)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38997356).

**6.** [Android N - Change Locale in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44554626).

**7.** [RTL layout bug in android Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46296202).

Comment: I know you said all versions less than 8.0 are fine, but have you tested 7.0? The resources framework changed how it handled locales starting with API 24.

Comment: What changes are you talking about?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support

Comment: @BenP. Thank you, but it is working properly on devices with Android 7.0 / 7.1. Multiple locale support does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Hm, okay. I was just surprised that a lot of the text changed to English.

Comment: can u check device  Developer Options in Settings, check Force RTL layout Direction is on or not

Comment: @BenP. What you have pointed out is really something we should think about when dealing with these kind of situations. However, the changes brought in API level 24 (Android  7.0) will only result in better matching of locales. I don't think it will cause any harm even for apps made for lower versions. But in API level 25 (Oreo), things are little bit different. The `updateConfiguration ()` method itself is deprecated. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227377/7594961).

Comment: Does Force RTL work for those devices?

Comment: @AadityaBrahmbhatt and BhuvaneshwaranVellingiri - force RTL helps somewhat with layout direction, but the core problem is intact. Incorrect resources are still getting loaded.

Comment: @Y.S. I had similar problem just realised you have multiple locale for single country. Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete solution to this problem consists of three steps:

**STEP 1**:

In the `onCreate()` of your `BaseActivity` (or all your `Activity`s), set the `Locale` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // set the Locale the very first thing
    Utils.setLocale(Utils.getSavedLocale());
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ......
    ......

}
```

where `getSavedLocale()` is the `Locale` corresponding to the current region (this will be specific for your project ... ).

And the method `Utils.setLocale(...)` is defined as follows:

```
public static void setLocale(Locale locale){
    Context context = MyApplication.getInstance();
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    // updateConfiguration(...) is deprecated in N
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25) {
        context = context.getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
            resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

This sets the correct `Locale` in every `Activity`. This is enough for apps supporting API level 25. For API level 26 & above, STEP 2 and STEP 3 are also required.

**STEP 2**:

Override the following method in your `BaseActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    newBase = Utils.getLanguageAwareContext(newBase);
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
}
```

where the function `getLanguageAwareContext(...)` is defined as follows:

```
public static Context getLanguageAwareContext(Context context){
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale locale = getIntendedLocale();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}
```

This, along with STEP 1, sets the correct `Locale` in every `Activity` of your app for API level 26 and above.

One more step, however, is required for setting the language direction correctly ...

**STEP 3**:

In the `onCreate()` of your `BaseActivity`, add the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ....
    ....

    // yup, it's a legit bug ... :)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(Utils.isRTL()
                ? View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL : View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);


    }

    ....
    ....
}
```

where the `isRTL()` function is defined as follows:

```
public static boolean isRTL(){
    return TextUtilsCompat.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(Locale.getDefault()) == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
}
```

The above steps should take care of all issues (at least regarding setting the `Locale` and text direction) on all extant versions of Android.

Answer (score 4):

The method [`Resources#updateConfiguration (Configuration config, DisplayMetrics metrics)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#updateConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)) is **deprecated in API level 25**.

The doc suggests to use [`Context#createConfigurationContext (Configuration overrideConfiguration)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#createConfigurationContext(android.content.res.Configuration))

You can simply make a base activity which is a common parent of all the activities as shown below.

```
public class BaseActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LANGUAGE_CODE_ENGLISH = "en";
    private static final String LANGUAGE_CODE_ARABIC = "ar";

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(getLanguageAwareContext(newBase));
    }

    private static Context getLanguageAwareContext(Context context) {
        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(new Locale(getLanguageCode()));
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    // Rewrite this method according to your needs
    private static String getLanguageCode() {
        return LANGUAGE_CODE_ARABIC;
    }
}
```

## Notes

- `getLanguageCode()` should return language code. Typically the language code or any other data representing it is stored in preferences.
- To change languages dynamically, recreate activity after setting appropriate language code into preferences.
- Use activity context rather than application context to access any locale specific resources. In other words, use `this` or `ActivityName.this` from activities and `getActivity()` from fragments instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 4):

The [**`updateConfiguration()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#updateConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)) method was <del>deprecated</del>

Now we need to use [**`createConfigurationContext()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#createConfigurationContext(android.content.res.Configuration))

I have managed this way

> create a new class **`ContextWrapper`**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.LocaleList;

import java.util.Locale;

public class ContextWrapper extends android.content.ContextWrapper {

    public ContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, Locale newLocale) {

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            configuration.setLocale(newLocale);

            LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(newLocale);
            LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
            configuration.setLocales(localeList);

            context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLocale(newLocale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);

        } else {
            configuration.locale = newLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(configuration, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        return new ContextWrapper(context);
    }}
```

> create a new  class of **`BaseActivity`**

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by nilesh on 20/3/18.
 */

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {

        Locale newLocale;

        String lang = new PrefManager(newBase).getLanguage();

        if (lang.equals("zh_CN")) {
            newLocale = new Locale("zh");
        } else {
            newLocale = new Locale(lang);
        }


        Context context = ContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, newLocale);
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
    }
}
```

> Create a `PrefManager` class to store locale

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class PrefManager {

    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private final String LANGUAGE = "language";
    private final String PREF = "user_data";

    public PrefManager(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        this.prefs = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);
        return this.prefs.getString(LANGUAGE, "en_US");
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.editor = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0).edit();
        this.editor.putString(LANGUAGE, language);
        this.editor.apply();
    }

}
```

> Now you need to extends your  BaseActivity  in your all  activity   like

```
public class OrdersActivity extends BaseActivity
```

> Now when your need to change `Locale` just update the value in `PrefManager` and restart your activity

```
    PrefManager prefManager= new PrefManager(this);
    prefManager.setLanguage("zh_CN");
    //  restart your activity
```

### NOTE

[You can download source code from github repo](https://github.com/RathodNilesh14/LocaleChange)

Comment: its not working. updating everything except layouts directions

Comment: @ZaidMirza sorry to here that can u explain more about it because the same code is working fine in my live project

Comment: I have fixed the issue. View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LOCALE was not working on 'Oreo'

Comment: @ZaidMirza *I have fixed the issue* happy to here that happy coding 

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setLocale(final Context ctx, final String lang) {
    AppSettings.getInstance(ctx).save(PrefKeys.language, lang);
    final Locale loc = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(loc);
    final Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.locale = loc;
    ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(cfg, null);
}
```

Change to English:  `setLocale(getActivity(), "en";`

Change to Arabic : `setLocale(getActivity(), "ar");`

After this you need to restart the application to get the Language change effects.

Comment: Thanks. I *am* calling `resources.updateConfiguration()`, and its working properly below Android 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Resources.updateConfiguration is deprecated use this instead :

```
 fun setLocale(old: Context, locale: Locale): Context {
    val oldConfig = old.resources.configuration
    oldConfig.setLocale(locale)
    return old.createConfigurationContext(oldConfig)
}

override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase?.let { setLocale(it, Locale("ar")) })
}
```

In Java

```
private Context setLocale(Context old, Locale locale) {
    Configuration oldConfig = old.getResources().getConfiguration();
    oldConfig.setLocale(locale);
    return old.createConfigurationContext(oldConfig);
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(setLocale(newBase, new Locale("ar")));
}
```

Comment: Whoa what language is that? Is it Kotlin? Sure doesn't look like Java ... :)

Comment: @Y.S. added java :) yep its kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Totally closed the app because i think it is making cache in background.

Use below code thats how I achieved it in my case, you also can give it a try:

```
 Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(ctc, SplashActivity.class);
                int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
                PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctc, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)ctc.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
                System.exit(0);
```