# Language change is not changing the text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a drop down, user can either choose `English` or `Spanish` language.

The issue is that on language changed, it converts date, time, progress dialog text to spanish or english, but the strings that i defined are not converted to the specified language.

Although they do convert after 1 or 2 clicks, so when i click on `ES` it won't change strings to `ES`, but then i click on `EN`, it will work and convert all string to `ES`, which is not the desired result.

When user taps on any language i execute following code.

```
languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        selectedLanguage=  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language_array)[i];
        loadLanguage(selectedLanguage.toLowerCase());
 }
```

The `load language` method perfoms these operations.

```
    public void loadLanguage(String language){

        String languageToLoad  = language;
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setLocale(locale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


        recreate(); 
 }
```

At each activity i have added following code.

```
  @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(LanguagePreference.getInstance().getUserLanguage(newBase));
        Context context = ContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, locale);
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
    }
```

Following is my Context Wrapper class.

```
  public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, Locale newLocale) {

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            configuration.setLocale(newLocale);

            LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(newLocale);
            LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
            configuration.setLocales(localeList);

            context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLocale(newLocale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);

        } else {
            configuration.locale = newLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(configuration, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        return new ContextWrapper(context);
    }}
```

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270630/7666442

Comment: are you sure the respective es strings are available against those keys ?

Comment: @SaraTirmizi : Yes they are, and they actually work sometimes, but if  i start changing language frequently then they stop working, or sometimes they does not change language at all.

Comment: @NileshRathod: Yes i checked that answer

Comment: @Kirmani88 this is the problem , changing basecontext takes time , rapidly changing may cause this issue, make sure to add delay may be 500 after changing language , this will resolve the issue

Comment: @SaraTirmizi : Thanks, i have added a delay, but still its updating strings sometimes and does not update any few times.

Comment: @NileshRathod:  If i click on any other activities it loads and works fine, and if i revisit the base activity it also loads fine, the issue only occurs if i stay on the same activity.

Comment: @Kirmani88 after changing language did u restart the activitys

Comment: @SaraTirmizi : If i click on any other activities it loads and works fine, and if i revisit the base activity it also loads fine, the issue only occurs if i stay on the same activity, it just reloads the activity, updates date string, but does not update strings that are defined in my strings.xml file.

Comment: @NileshRathod : Yes it did,I execute `recreate(); `

Comment: @Kirmani88 may that the issue try to restart your activity like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3974828/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod: tired that, but the issue is still there. One thing i noticed that, it updates dates and other strings that are part of system, but does not updates strings defined in my app.When i revist aactivity, all strings are updated.