# locale resets to default when rotating landscape to reverse landscape in Nougat+ devices

Tags: android, locale

I'm developing an app with multi-language feature, It supports `landscape` and `reverseLandscape` orientations. Its working fine up-to Marshmallow devices.

But in `Nougat+` devices, when I change orientation from landscape to reverse landscape,it seems locale gets resets to default one. After this, all the newly creating `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Dialog` having English language.

**BaseActivity**

This is what my simplified base activity looks like

```
abstract class LocaleBaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    public override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(refreshLocale(newBase, LanguageVO.getInstance().LocalizationCode[0]))
    }

    fun refreshLocale(context: Context, lang: String): Context {
        val locale = Locale(lang.toLowerCase())
        val configuration = context.resources.configuration // getBaseContext().
        configuration.locale = locale
        configuration.setLocale(Locale(lang.toLowerCase()))
        context.resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, context.resources.displayMetrics)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        return context
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270630/7666442

Comment: when using createConfigurationContext, I couldn't change locale second time, It seems I've to restart my app.

Comment: shared preferences in on create.