# RTL not Support after removing app from recent (killing)

Tags: android, right-to-left

I am working on multi language application which contain Arabic language. I applied locale at 2 places

- When change language
- In the Splash Screen

At the first time when I change language and  restart the application. Its working fine

When I kill the application but pressing back button and launch application again. Its also working fine.

But When I remove application from recent and launch the application, RTL not supported.

Any idea about this issue ? Please help me.

I think RTL and applied local not worked properly after removing application from recent.

Comment: Totally messed up question, i am not able to understand it, please state the problem clearly

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh   Now I Edit the question

Comment: what issue you are seeing actually

Comment: Everything is perfect means locale applied also rtl work when I kill application by pressing back press. But Not work when I kill the app by removed from recent. Languages is changed, all label are also changed but RTL not work .

Comment: why dont you restart your app whenever the language is changed

Comment: Think you are the user. You change the language from English to Arabic. language is changed app is restart. But now as a user you removed all recent apps to free the memory. And After some time you open the app. Labels are changed to Arabic but layout RTL not  work. This is my problem

Comment: do you face this in a specific device or version?

Comment: I test with Android pie and Nougat. Means it is OS specific issue

Comment: which one is no working

Comment: I just test in moto e which has marshmallow 6.0. Working perfect.

Comment: Issue Done after try this one   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187959/resources-and-layout-direction-rendered-incorrectly-only-on-android-8-0-and-abov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lots of R&D I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187959/resources-and-layout-direction-rendered-incorrectly-only-on-android-8-0-and-abov). Tried this and issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not catch the current language so when app load again load a default
language 
when lanch app again print language to know which language you init app

Comment: yes I print the current language its Arabic applied. But RTL not worked. Even all string resource file was also applied.

Comment: try with different  devices and check if the problem with all devices or with specific  version

Comment: I test with Android pie and Nougat

Comment: try but init language before setcontentview also try with older version

Comment: I just test in moto e which has marshmallow 6.0. Working perfect.