# appLocale setting in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made radio group where user can select their desire language and app language changes to selected language but i am not able to use the functions (not sure how to!)

## What I did?

1. I've made `settingsActivity`
2. I've added radio group
3. I've wrote `setAppLocale` function
4. I've set `onRadioButtonClicked` to change languages

## Code

`settingsActivity.java`

```
package com.xxxxxx.xxxxx;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

import java.util.Locale;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }


    //locale settings
    public void setAppLocale(String localeCode) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            conf.setLocale(new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase()));
        } else {
            conf.locale = new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase());
        }

        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }

    // application language switch
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_indo:
                if (checked)
                    setAppLocale("id");
                    break;
            case R.id.radio_english:
                if (checked)
                    setAppLocale("en");
                    break;
        }
    }

}
```

`settings_activity.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/settings">


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4sp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/appLang"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/applangtext"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/applangtextstring" />

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_indo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                        android:text="@string/indoLang" />

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_english"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                        android:text="@string/englishLang" />

            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

## Question

I need to make 2 things happen in my java file:

1. Mark current language radio input as selected
2. Make changes when user select another radio button

> The question is how do I connect `onRadioButtonClicked` to
>   `setAppLocale`? as well as return current language `onCreate` in order
>   to show current language selected?

## Update

Based on answer below here is my latest update and extra files that I've added. **Yet my language switch doesn't work**

`settingsActivity.java`

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import java.util.Locale;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PrefManager prefManager; //added
    RadioButton radio_indo, radio_english; //added
    RadioGroup appLang; //added

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);

        //added
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);

        radio_indo = findViewById(R.id.radio_indo);
        radio_english = findViewById(R.id.radio_english);
        appLang = findViewById(R.id.appLang);

        if (prefManager.getLanguage().equals("en")) {
            radio_english.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            radio_english.setChecked(true);
        }

        // application language switch (added)
        appLang.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkId) {
                switch (checkId) {
                    case R.id.radio_indo:
                        prefManager.setLanguage("id");
                        // you need to restart or recreate your activity after locale change
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_english:
                        prefManager.setLanguage("en");
                        // you need to restart or recreate your activity after locale change
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }


    //locale settings
    public void setAppLocale(String localeCode) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            conf.setLocale(new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase()));
        } else {
            conf.locale = new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase());
        }

        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }

     // removed my old function as new function added to onCreate

}
```

`PrefManager.java` added class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class PrefManager {
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private final String LANGUAGE = "language";
    private final String PREF = "user_data";

    public PrefManager(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        this.prefs = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);
        return this.prefs.getString(LANGUAGE, "en");
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.editor = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0).edit();
        this.editor.putString(LANGUAGE, language);
        this.editor.apply();
    }
}
```

`BaseActivity.java` added class

```
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by nilesh on 20/3/18.
 */

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {

        Locale newLocale;

        String lang = new PrefManager(newBase).getLanguage();

        if (lang.equals("en")) {
            newLocale = new Locale("en");
        } else {
            newLocale = new Locale(lang);
        }


        Context context = ContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, newLocale);
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
    }
}
```

`settings_activity.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/settings">


    <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/appLang"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/applangtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/applangtextstring" />

        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_indo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/indoLang" />

        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_english"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/englishLang" />

    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is all I have regarding to language switch.

> PS-1: based on provided solution in answer comments I should have add
>   `BaseActivity` as extends in all my activites but as all my activities
>   are `kotlin` not `java` (except settingsActivity) I was not able to
>   add it.
>
> PS-2: even if not getting translatations is because I couldn't add
>   extends at very least I should be able to see translations in my
>   settingsActivity which is `java` right?

Any idea why this switch doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**

[You can download source code from github repo](https://github.com/RathodNilesh14/LocaleChange)

> Mark current language radio input as selected

Then you need to save your locale change flag/state inside `SharedPreferences`

**SAMPLE CODE** follow these steps

> Create one class name `PrefManager`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class PrefManager {
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private final String LANGUAGE = "language";
    private final String PREF = "user_data";

    public PrefManager(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        this.prefs = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);
        return this.prefs.getString(LANGUAGE, "en");
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.editor = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0).edit();
        this.editor.putString(LANGUAGE, language);
        this.editor.apply();
    }
}
```

> Now add below code/ condition in your `settingsActivity.java`

```
public class JavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PrefManager prefManager;
    RadioButton radio_indo, radio_english;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_java);
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        radio_indo = findViewById(R.id.radio_indo);
        radio_english = findViewById(R.id.radio_english);

        if (prefManager.getLanguage().equals("en")) {
            radio_english.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            radio_english.setChecked(true);
        }
    }

}
```

> Make changes when user select another radio button

- When the user changes the language  you need to update it `SharedPreferences`
- You need to restart or recreate your activity after locale change

Note : you should use `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()` instead of `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class JavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PrefManager prefManager;
    RadioButton radio_indo, radio_english;
    RadioGroup appLang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_java);
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);

        radio_indo = findViewById(R.id.radio_indo);
        radio_english = findViewById(R.id.radio_english);
        appLang = findViewById(R.id.appLang);

        if (prefManager.getLanguage().equals("en")) {
            radio_english.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            radio_english.setChecked(true);
        }

        appLang.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkId) {
                switch (checkId) {
                    case R.id.radio_indo:
                        prefManager.setLanguage("id");
                        // you need to restart or recreate your activity after locale change
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_english:
                        prefManager.setLanguage("en");
                        // you need to restart or recreate your activity after locale change
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

> Please follow this my previous answer to change locale runtime

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270630/7666442

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but i have very silly question as this is my first attempt with android studio, where should i create this `Create one class name PrefManager` and what option should i chose from `new -> ?` :) SORRY :D

Comment: @mafortis it's ok no problem please check this [How To Create New Java Class in Android Studio](https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/how-to-create-new-java-class-in-android-studio)

Comment: hi :) , sorry but i didn't get this part `Note : you should use RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() instead of android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` where should i use `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()` in my xml?

Comment: @mafortis whenever you use `RadioGroup` you should use `OnCheckedChangeListener()` to get selected `radioButton` check this [How to set OnClickListener on a RadioButton in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8323778/7666442)

Comment: and as you added `appLang.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {` in `onCreate()` should i remove `public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view)` now?

Comment: @mafortis Remove it from`onCreate()` and also from `XML`

Comment: i did all you said now i get current locale selected in my view but nothing translates when i select other language.

Comment: @mafortis after select you need to restart your activity, BTW witch langue your using and have you create two separate `string.xml` files?

Comment: my settings is java but my other activities are kotlin, yes i have two string files every time i add new string i provide translation of that as well

Comment: @mafortis have you checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270630/7666442

Comment: @mafortis which two languages you are using in your app?

Comment: yes i created new class based on your answer there however i wasn't able to use extends in kotlin activities, but at least it should translate my settings activity which is java right? ps: how do i reset my activities after selecting new lang?

Comment: @mafortis `how do i reset my activities after selecting new lang?` you need to restart that activity or try to restart app

Comment: @mafortis find [my contact info from here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod?tab=profile) I will send you demo project tonight

Comment: Hi, I didn't get your respond on FB but I updated my question would you please check it?

Comment: @mafortis sorry for late replay  i was little busy, i will provide you sample code soon

Comment: @mafortis [You can download source code from github repo](https://github.com/RathodNilesh14/LocaleChange)

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing that but i wasn't able to see `java/kt` files in order to see classes and functions there is just `xml` files. how should i compare to see if my code is right?

Comment: ok found them and trying to make changes as your code however when i use Base class instead of appcomponent() all my activities are become red in other word I can't build my app due to this error. another thing was i was using api 14 your code requires api 17 now I'm downloading api 17 hopefully this solves issue of base extends

Comment: hi, it is working perfectly, i wished to have radio group instead of buttons but it's fine as well. thank you so much.

Comment: hi man, after very long time I've got issue with your solution :) the solution works just fine if i use debug app but after uploading app on google store and downloading it from there the localization won't work. it selects new language but doesn't get translations. any idea? i have read some people says google store will config apps based on devices languages and ignores users settings there must be some additional codes to avoid this google store setups