# Change language issue at runtime for device above 7.0

Tags: android, build.gradle, androidx

I have a problem really similar to this one : [Language change issue after updating to androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900554/language-change-issue-after-updating-to-androidx-appcompatappcompat1-1-0) except that it is working great for me for Api 24 and below, but it doesn't work at all for Api 26 and above (couldn't test Api 25).

Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' //DO NOT UPGRADE - Translation issue
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Code triggered when I click on a button

```
 /**
     * Select language application
     */
    public static void defineLanguage(ImageButton button, final String value, final Activity activity, final Activity source) {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Locale locale = new Locale(value);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
    activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, source.getClass());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                activity.finish();
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Should I also wait for a fix from Google or is my problem slightly different?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58109994/7666442

Comment: Thanks to your comment I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187959/resources-and-layout-direction-rendered-incorrectly-only-on-android-8-0-and-abov/52270630#52270630 and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help!